# Timeout Issue in Looping Through Hackerrank Example

Tags: python, timeout

can anyone explain why my code for a hacker rank example is timing out. I'm new to whole idea of efficiency of code based on processing time. The code seems to work on small sets, but once I start testing cases using large datasets it times out. I've provided a brief explanation of the method and its purpose for context. But if you could provide any tips if you notice functions I'm using that might consume a large amount of runtime that would be great.

Complete the migratoryBirds function below.
Params: arr: an array of tallies of species of birds sighted by index.
For example. arr = [Type1 = 1, Type2 = 4, Type3 = 4, Type4 = 4, Type5 = 5, Type6 = 3]
Return the lowest type of the the mode of sightings. In this case 4 sightings is the
mode. Type2 is the lowest type that has the mode. So return integer 2.

```
def migratoryBirds(arr):
    # list of counts of occurrences of birds types with the same 
    # number of sightings
    bird_count_mode = []
    for i in range(1, len(arr) + 1):
        occurr_count = arr.count(i)
        bird_count_mode.append(occurr_count)
        
    most_common_count = max(bird_count_mode)
    common_count_index = bird_count_mode.index(most_common_count) + 1
    # Find the first occurrence of that common_count_index in arr
    # lowest_type_bird = arr.index(common_count_index) + 1
    # Expect Input: [1,4,4,4,5,3]
    # Expect Output: [1 0 1 3 1 0], 3, 4
    return bird_count_mode, most_common_count, common_count_index
```

P.S. Thank you for the edit Chris Charley. I just tried to edit it at the same time

Comment: This is completely wrong: `occurr_count = arr.count(i)`. `i` is a list index, but `count()` is for counting list elements. It should be `arr.count(arr[i])`

Comment: And even if you did that correctly, it's an O(n^2) algorithm. You can count elements in O(n) by using a dictionary. And there's a library function `collections.Counter()` that does this for you.

Comment: @Barmar So I take it collections.Counter() is more efficient? Sorry, I'm new to the concept of O(n^2) vs O(n), but I'm researching it right now.

Comment: Each call to `arr.count(i)` is O(n), and you perform them n times, making the algorithm O(n^2).

Comment: `collections.Counter()` presumably uses something like `for i in list: counter[i]+=1`

Answer (score 0):

Use `collections.Counter()` to create a dictionary that maps species to their counts. Get the maximum count from this, then get all the species with that count. Then search the list for the first element of one of those species.

```
import collections

def migratoryBirds(arr):
    species_counts = collections.Counter(arr)
    most_common_count = max(species_counts.values())
    most_common_species = {species for species, count in species_counts if count = most_common_count}

    for i, species in arr:
        if species in most_common_species:
            return i
```

Comment: The instructions were unclear for the problem itself. But I'm pretty sure based on the answers of the problem that they meant to say return the mode of bird types, rather than return the lowest. It's besides the point though. What I'm really wondering is if the counter library function is more efficient.

Comment: I'd expect the counter library to be O(n), since that's the natural way to implement it using a dictionary. And the instructions clearly say to return the lowest when there are multiple instances of the mode.